# What is the proper convention for locking in api's?

Tags: c, multithreading

The question is about coding style. How do I create functions which are external facing yet handle locking well.

```
void Timer_start(Timer *t){ //this is a user facing function
    if (t->state == Timer_paused){ 
        Timer_resume(t);               
    } else {
        Timer_initialize(t);
    }
}

void Timer_resume(Timer *t){ //this is also a user facing function
    Lock_acquire(t->lock);
    //...do work 
    Lock_release(t->lock);
}

void Timer_initialize(Timer *t){ //and so is this
    //...do work (just to illustrate the the functions arent necessarily simply wrapped with the locking functions)
    Lock_acquire(t->lock);
    //...do work 
    Lock_release(t->lock);
}
```

In the example, `Timer_start` should be wrapped in `Lock_acquire` and `Lock_release` like the other two functions because of the possibility of being interrupted immediately after the state check. The problem is that I cannot wrap the function in the proper locking functions since the called functions themselves acquire the lock. Is there a coding style that handles this problem well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have local (static) functions that do the guts of _resume and _init and then all the externally facing functions just have the locking and call the internal functions.

```
static void Timer_resume_impl(Timer *t) {
   do work
}
static void Timer_initialize_impl(Timer *t) {
   do work
}

void Timer_start(Timer *t) {
   Lock_acquire(t->lock);
   if (t->state == Timer_paused) {
      Timer_resume_impl(t);
   }
   else {
      Timer_initialize_impl(t);
   } 
   Lock_release(t->lock);
}
void Timer_resume(Timer *t) {
   Lock_acquire(t->lock);
   Timer_resume_impl(t);
   Lock_release(t->lock);
}
...
```

Comment: Are you speculating, or is this really the "tried and true" way of doing it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey of course it's "tried and true" (one of the possibilities). Ever heard of `unlocked_stdio`?

Comment: Just asking.  You started your answer with "Why not?"  Implying that your technique is experimental.

Comment: Lol, i just predicted this answer with the new edit. The new example shows that the functions arent simply wrapped with the locking functions. You could theoretically expand the scope of the lock to do so, but that would negatively impact performance. Furthermore, it leads to rather messy code where you have a duplicate function wherever the code needs locking.

Comment: Well, if its good enough for stdio, i guess that this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `Timer_resume_unlocked`  and `Timer_start_unlocked`, which would require the caller to take care of locking. Then make `Timer_resume` and `Timer_start` be a wrappers which do nothing but locking and a call to their `_unlocked` counterparts.

It is up to you to decide if you make `_unlocked` variants a part of your public API, but generally, users are more likely to want them eventually then you hope.

Another option is to leave proper locking to the callers of your API if it is *possible* to implement correctly on their side. It's usually possible to add a dumb "lock everything" safety layer to a library which does not use locks, but it's impossible to *remove* locking from the guts of library when it turns out to be superfluous.

Or you can use recursive locking (there are [good arguments](http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html) against it, but it remains a possibility).

Comment: I was thinking about recursive locking, but it seems that the implementation would be rather nasty as you would have to store a map from threadid to lock count per lock.

Comment: Is it unavailable on your platform? (Windows critical sections are recursive with no other options, and pthread mutexes have an attribute for that). Anyway, there is no need to store a map, it's enough to store an owner thread id and a counter *right in the lock structure*.